# Anaconda Numpy ImportError Osx

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, importerror, dlopen

Hello so first of all that's my problem right now.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
     15 try:
---> 16     from . import multiarray
     17 except ImportError as exc:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/marc.seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): can't resolve symbol ___stack_chk_guard in /Users/marc.seng/anaconda3/lib/libopenblas.dylib because dependent dylib #2 could not be loaded in /Users/marc.seng/anaconda3/lib/libopenblas.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    140         return loader(*packages, **options)
    141 
--> 142     from . import add_newdocs
    143     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    144                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, zeros
     13 from .ufunclike import isneginf, isposinf

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py in <module>()
     24 Original error was: %s
     25 """ % (exc,)
---> 26     raise ImportError(msg)
     27 finally:
     28     for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: dlopen(/Users/marc.seng/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): can't resolve symbol ___stack_chk_guard in /Users/marc.seng/anaconda3/lib/libopenblas.dylib because dependent dylib #2 could not be loaded in /Users/marc.seng/anaconda3/lib/libopenblas.dylib
```

I've been trying to fix that problem since a few days. But I wasn't able to find a solution until now. 
I'm a beginner, and I'm doing some Udemy-Courses right now. A few weeks ago I tried to get Spark-Hadoop running on my Osx. For that I added:

```
if which java > /dev/null; then export
JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home); fi

export
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
if which pyspark > /dev/null; then
        export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/"
        export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPA$
        export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPAT$ fi
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.2 export
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/libexec/etc/hadoop export
SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.1.0
```

this to my `.bash_profile`

Then I've tried to get spyder running again because it didn't open when i tried to use it. After a bit work around i was able to get it running. 
I can't remember what i did to get it running. But since then I'm not able to import numpy anymore.
I tried to reinstall Numpy. What didn't work.
I tried to update `libopenblas` what didn't worked either, because Conda tells me I already have the newest version.

So if anyone could help me I would be very thankful.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to reinstall anaconda3